# How do you create a new celery queue for a periodic task for a django application?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I need to create a periodic task that will run every five minutes to check an azure service bus for new messages.  Every time it runs, I would like the worker process to remain active for five minutes, whether there are new messages waiting or not.  I need to specify a new queue for these tasks as well.

In a django project with celery installed, where do I configure this new queue and above mentioned configuration?

I have created a new python file containing a class that inherits from PeriodicTask, passing the parameter run_every = 300 to run the task every 5 minutes. I would like to assign it to azure_queue, but don't know where to configure it

```py
def CheckForProfileUpdates(PeriodicTask)
   run_every = 300

   def run(self, queue_name='azure_queue'):
        result = check_service_bus_for_profile_update()
        if update_was_found(result):
            update = json.loads(result.body)
            #do business logic here
```

I would like these tasks to execute every 5 minutes, and each time, the worker must remain active throughout those five minutes, in a dedicated queue called 'azure_queue'.  Again, where do I specify these settings using django and celery?